# When I try to restart a docker container I get a message that the container already exists

Tags: docker

When I run docker restart I get a response like the following:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container 97dea473cc0e: container "97dea473cc0e44bb3dfeb773cc6e3b7766fb45cb01e8cba5646bd319974da7ce": already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
docker-containerd-ctr --address /run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock --namespace moby c rm <containerd id>
```

it will allow you to restart the container. So in this case run:

```
docker-containerd-ctr --address /run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock --namespace moby c rm 97dea473cc0e44bb3dfeb773cc6e3b7766fb45cb01e8cba5646bd319974da7ce
docker restart 97dea473cc0e
```

Comment: could you tell us what exact command you were using previously?